# haskell modulus function using repeated subtractions

Tags: haskell

I am required to write a modulus function (using repeated subtractions and not using the primitive mod function).

```
mod' :: Int -> Int -> Int
mod' x 0 = 0
mod' 0 x = x
mod' x y | x >= y =  (mod' (x-y) y)
         | otherwise = y
```

I did this but this is not working. It compiles, but I get incorrect answers like this:

```
*Main> 7 `mod'` 4
4
*Main> 3 `mod'` 5
5
```

What is wrong?

Comment: The next time you ask a question, remember to tell what part is not working by providing an examples (what input you passed, what result you got and what you were expecting).

Answer (score 4):

`otherwise = y`

This is wrong: when `x < y`, `x mod y == x`.

Also, shouldn't `` x `mod` 0 `` be an error?

EDIT: And, `mod' 0 x = 0`, not x.

Comment: @AndrewC yes, that's exactly what I mean. Tried to use mod as an infix operator, but `s always get messed up with the "code sample" markup. Edited.

Comment: Ah yes - this used to annoy me greatly until I found the trick: use `` at the start and end, and then you can use ` inside fine.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the line that did the work, `mod' x y | x >= y =  (mod' (x-y) y)`, you had the role of the two arguments transposed; `mod' x y` means ``x `mod'` y`, the remainder on dividing`x`by`y`.

```
mod' :: Int -> Int -> Int
mod' x 0 = x
mod' 0 x = 0
mod' x y | x >= y =  (mod' (x-y) y)
         | otherwise = x
```

## Zero

`div` and `mod` come from the equation

```
x = (x `div` y) * y + (x `mod` y)
```

You can argue that if `y==0` then since `_ * 0` is `0`, `` x `mod` 0 `` should be `x` to make the equation work. 
However this assumes a non-strict `*`, since `` x `div` y `` is `error "divide by zero"`. In Haskell, `*` is strict, so the equation breaks down anyway. Perhaps it's better to warn the user they did a calculation involving division by zero rather than silently going ahead, giving

```
mod' _ 0 = error "division by zero"
```

## How is mod supposed to work for negative numbers anyway?

OK, the main thing is that since it's a remainder, `` x `mod` y `` is supposed to be between `y` and zero, and not equal to `y`, so we can calculate `` 7 `mod` 3 `` like this:

[image: repeatedly take 3 until answer is under 3]

Well what if we look at something `mod (-3)`? Now "between `y` and zero" means the remainder should be negative, so we can calculate `` (-7) `mod` (-3) `` this way:

[image: repeatedly take minus three until answer is above -3]

Of course, taking minus three is the same as adding three, but the main point is that we get the same calculation and answer, just with a change of sign:

```
(-x) `mod` (-y) = -(x `mod` y)
```

In both those cases, the sign of `x` and `y` matched. What if they differ? Firstly, we could have positive `y`:

[image: repeatedly add three until answer is above zero]

Secondly we could have negative `y`:

[image: repeatedly add minus three until answer is below zero]

As we can see, the method is different, but the change of sign rule

```
(-x) `mod` (-y) = -(x `mod` y)
```

still stands.

## So what should we do to the function?

Step 0: check for zeros
Step 1: check for negative `y`. Use the change of sign rule if so.
Step 2: check for positive `x`. If so take `y` until you're under `y`.
Step 3: otherwise add `y` until you're over zero.

In code, that's

```
mod' :: Int -> Int -> Int
mod' x 0 = error "mod by zero"
mod' 0 x = 0
mod' x y | y < 0 = - (mod' (-x) (-y))
         | x > 0 = modpos x
         | otherwise = modneg x
where
  modpos x | x < y = x
           | otherwise = modpos (x-y)
  modneg x | x >= 0 = x
           | otherwise = modneg (x+y)
```

And a quick check:

```
ghci> all id [x `mod` y == x `mod'` y | x <- [-10 .. 10], y<- [-10 .. 10],y/=0]
True
```

shows we got the logic right.

Comment: Might as well mention that it fails for negative numbers as well.

Comment: @hammar I think I've dealt with that in this edit now. Just a little bit.